# Lambda function doesn't return float

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda

I've written the following code for computing the in-center of a triangle. This code is supposed to be for code-golf. Any help would be appreciated.

```python
d = lambda x,y: ((x[0]-y[0])**2+(x[1]-y[1])**2)**0.5
e = lambda w,x,y,z: float(d(y,z)*x[w]+d(z,x)*y[w]+d(x,y)*z[w])/(d(x,y)+d(y,z)+d(z,x))
a,b,c=eval(input())
px,py=e(0,a,b,c),e(1,a,b,c)
print('[%f,%f]' % (px,py))
```

Input:

```python
([1,2],[2,2],[1,2])
```

Expected Output:

```python
[1.2928932188134525, 1.7071067811865475]
```

Actual Output:

```python
[1.000000,2.000000]
```

Comment: If you must use eval (you shouldn't), use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python is doing the maths correctly. Either your logic is wrong or your input is wrong or your expected output is wrong. Given your input, the only possible output for `d` is `0` or `1` (the Cartesian distance between two points). Doing this, we can simply `e` to see what it might output for the first function call.

Given:

```
w = 0
x = [1, 2]
y = [2, 2]
z = [1, 2]
result = float(d(y,z)*x[w]+d(z,x)*y[w]+d(x,y)*z[w])/(d(x,y)+d(y,z)+d(z,x))
```

becomes:

```
result = float(d([2, 2],[1, 2])*[1, 2][0]+d([1, 2],[1, 2])*[2, 2][0]+d([1, 2],[2, 2])*[1, 2][0])/(d([1, 2],[2, 2])+d([2, 2],[1, 2])+d([1, 2],[1, 2]))
```

becomes:

```
result = float((1.*1 + 0.*2 + 1.*1) / (1. + 1. + 0))
```

becomes:

```
result = float(2. / 2.)
result = float(1.)
result = 1. # not 1.2928932188134525
```

After that, it's up to you to figure out what's wrong as you haven't specified why the expected output is the expected output.

Comment: See this output from the interpreter:
 
    >>> d = lambda x,y: ((x[0]-y[0])**2+(x[1]-y[1])**2)**0.5

    >>> e = lambda w,x,y,z: float(d(y,z)*x[w]+d(z,x)*y[w]+d(x,y)*z[w])/(d(x,y)+d(y,z)+d(z,x))
    >>> e(0,[1,1],[2,2],[1,2])
    Output: 1.2928932188134525
    >>> e(1,[1,1],[2,2],[1,2])
    Output: 1.7071067811865475

Comment: You've used a different input to the one specified in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that [1.000000,2.000000] isn't a correct answer? This code:

```
d = lambda x,y: round(((x[0]-y[0])**2.0+(x[1]-y[1])**2.0)**0.5, 12)
e = lambda w,x,y,z: float(round((d(y,z)*x[w]+d(z,x)*y[w]+d(x,y)*z[w])/(d(x,y)+d(y,z)+d(z,x)),12))
a,b,c= input()
px,py=e(0,a,b,c),e(1,a,b,c)
print px, py
```

return floating numbers, for example:

**in:** `([1.25325,2.34346], [2.25325,4.34346], [22.25325,22.34346])`

**out:** `2.559632791 4.11015248488`